# Rails duplicate sql query even with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have trouble understanding why are two duplicate sql queries generated in this situation:

I have a Post which `has_many :comments`

```
post = Post.where(id: 4).includes(:comments).first
```

generates these sql statements:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
SELECT "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."post_id" IN (4)
```

Now:

```
comment = post.comments.first
```

(no sql - good)
However:

```
post = comment.post
```

generates the same sql:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = 4 LIMIT 1
```

It seems like the objects are not bound internally. Is there a way I can do that manually to avoid the second sql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `inverse_of` to specify the bi-directional relationship. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#label-Bi-directional+associations):

> Specifying the :inverse_of option on associations lets you tell Active Record about inverse relationships and it will optimise object loading.

It may look redundant for simple cases, but associations are 1-way definitions.  Specifying `inverse_of` lets Rails know that the two relationships are inverse of one another, and solves problems like the one you're having.

```
# in post.rb
has_many :comments, :inverse_of => :post

# in comment.rb
belongs_to :post, :inverse_of => :comments
```